# Does being an ethereum validator post-merge require me to have a computer on running core Ethereum?

Tags: validators, the-merge

If I'm a validator post-merge, do I need to have a computer running to verify blocks on the network? If not, then how am I a validator?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a validator post-merge, you do need to have a computer running and nodes connected to the blockchain at all times. Therefore, a good internet connection is a must-have. Offline validator nodes will be penalized to encourage them to connect to the network at all times. The protocol will issue incentives and penalties every 6.5 minutes, or epoch.